# libgdx camera freezes unless window is moved around

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, rendering

I have been playing around with LibGDX for a good bit now and haven't found a problem I couldn't solve until now. When I run my project sometimes everything works perfectly fine but about 1 out of 10 times the camera will just refuse to update it seems unless the game window is either over another programs existing window or I physically grab the window with my mouse and move it around while moving my sprite around so that I can see it updating. anyone have any ideas what could be causing this?

```
@Override
public void create () {
    int tileSize = 16;
    int w = 30 * tileSize;
    int h = 17 * tileSize;
    viewport.setScreenSize(w, h);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(false,viewport.getScreenWidth(),viewport.getScreenHeight());
    camera.update();


    mapGenerator = new MapGenerator();

    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(mapGenerator.getTiledMap());

    spawner = new EntitySpawner(mapGenerator.getMapObjects());
    spawner.spawn();//there is a to do in the entity spawner class to move this else where

    sb = new SpriteBatch();

    hud = new Hud(camera);

    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

    Gdx.graphics.setResizable(false);//makes it so you can't just drag the game window to any size since its easy to distort it
    Gdx.graphics.setWindowedMode(1280,720);//resolution size windowed
}

@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);//background color
    Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc(GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


    //update the camera
    camera.position.x = spawner.player.sprite.getX();
    camera.position.y = spawner.player.sprite.getY();
    camera.update();
    tiledMapRenderer.setView(camera);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();

    timeElapsed += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();//simply time that has passed based off delta time


    sb.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    sb.begin(); //start the sprite batch
    spawner.draw(sb);//draw any entities with the spawner

    hud.draw(sb);//draw the HUD
    sb.end();//end the sprite batch

}
```

Comment: What is timeElapsed and where is it defined?

Comment: it is a private float variable that is initialized by "private float timeElapsed = 0;" above create() and was being passed to an animation.

Comment: Are there any other classes accessing camera?

Comment: No. This is the only class that uses camera at all and it should just be following the sprite coordinates.

Comment: Indeed, it should be working. I really don't know what the problem is, either look through your code again, all of it, to see if there's something gdx graphics related which may be stopping the camera, or wait for someone else.

Comment: But wait... Does player ever change? Does it become a different sprite?

Comment: Try just creating a player without spanner, store it in  variable and se if that works.